# Is it possible to make templates choose an alternate source line if an original source line fails to compile?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm looking for a relatively generic:

1. try to compile this line of code
2. if that succeeds, compile and use that line of code. Otherwise
3. use some other line of code

I've got a case where I'd like to selectively compile something based on whether the supplied functor is valid on `double`s:

```
//Some user supplied functor I can't modify which works on `int` but not `double`
template<typename T>
struct LShift : std::binary_function<T, T, T>
{
    T operator()(T lhs, T rhs)
    {
        return lhs << rhs;
    }
};

//Class that holds either an int or a double
class Example
{
    union
    {
        int intVal;
        double dblVal;
    } value;
    bool isIntType;
public:
    Example(int val)
        : isIntType(true)
    {
        value.intVal = val;
    }
    Example(double val)
        : isIntType(false)
    {
        value.dblVal = val;
    }
    int GetIntergalValue() const
    {
        return value.intVal;
    }
    double GetDoubleValue() const
    {
        return value.dblVal;
    }
    bool IsIntegral() const
    {
        return isIntType;
    }
};

//Does something with an example. I know that if the examples have `double` contents,
//that the functor passed will also be valid for double arguments.
template <template <typename Ty> class FunctorT>
Example DoSomething(const Example& lhs, const Example& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.IsIntergal() != rhs.IsIntergal())
    {
        throw std::logic_error("...");
    }
    if (lhs.IsIntegral())
    {
        return Example(FunctorT<int>(lhs.GetIntergalValue(), rhs.GetIntergalValue()));
    }
    else
    {
        return Example(FunctorT<double>(lhs.GetDoubleValue(), rhs.GetDoubleValue()));
    }
}


int main()
{
    DoSomething<LShift>();
}
```

I've never used SFINAE before, but this was my first attempt:

```
template <template <typename Ty> class FunctorT>
double DoDouble(double lhs, double rhs)
{
    return FunctorT<double>()(lhs, rhs);
}

template <template <typename Ty> class FunctorT>
double DoDouble(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    throw std::logic_error("That is not valid on floating types.");
}
```

I thought substitution would fail on the first overload (which would be selected because it's a better overload when passed doubles), and that control would then proceed to the second overload. However, the whole thing fails to compile anyway.

Is what I'm trying to do reasonable or possible?

Comment: Are you trying to transform a compile time error into a runtime error? What?

Comment: @Alf: That is correct. I've simplified things for this example; in the real program I know that the branch with doubles is never reached if something like left shift is passed. I know that, but the compiler doesn't. (The exception here is really more of an assert that says "you should have never gotten here")

Comment: i don't get it.. are you aiming for a compile time error or a run time error? If the latter, a simpler specialization of `LShift` ought to handle that?

Comment: If you want to have a starting guide on how SFINAE works, and on why what you do isn't using SFINAE, have a look at [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-10-of-10). :)

Comment: @Nim @Xeo: I've updated the example a bit... it's longer, but it might make more sense...

Answer (score 2):

Try this (it's off the cuff, may have syntax erors):

```
template < class Type >
Type ShiftLeft( Type lhs, Type rhs )
{
    return LShift( lhs, rhs );
}

template <>
double ShiftLeft( double lhs, double rhs )
{
    assert( "ShiftLeft is not valid on floating types." && false );
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can use SFINAE via Boost `enable_if`.

But there is a strong smell about it. The code where the specialization is not invoked (!) should most probably be refactored. In some way.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: The only "refactored" I have available would be to replace the templates I've got with macros, and I really don't want to do that. :( I've updated my example to be a bit closer to what I'm dealing with.